# If Statement in JavaScript for Getting Value from Select Input

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i get stuck with this problem. First, here is the codes :

#### JavaScript

```
function PilihKeterangan(isi)
{
    if (isi = 'A') {
        $('#keterangan').val("Sangat Baik : sangat aktif mengikuti latihan dan kegiatan ...");
    } else if (isi = "B") {
        $('#keterangan').val("Baik : aktif mengikuti latihan dan kegiatan ...");
    } else if (isi = 'C') {
        $('#keterangan').val("Cukup : cukup aktif mengikuti latihan dan kegiatan Kepramukaan ..."); 
    } else if (isi = 'X') {
        $('#keterangan').val("Kegiatan ini tidak dipilih oleh siswa / bukan menjadi pilihan siswa");
    } else {
        $('#keterangan').val("Pilihlah predikat A/B/C/X.");
    }

}
```

#### HTML

```
<select class="form-control" name="PREDIKAT_EKSTRA_UTS" onchange="PilihKeterangan(this.value)">
    <option selected value="">- Pilih -</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="X">X</option>
</select>
```

The problem is, it just can select first condition. If i click other option, the result is still first conddition. In example : If i select/click 'A' or 'B' or else one the result is always first condition.
But if i just passing select's value, it is works but not when i give it IF statement.

I just look from this tutorial about using IF statement in w3schools if the JavaScript is using '=' not the '==' :
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

I hope there are any reply. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Who is giving me -1 score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not syntaxt of if statement

you should do like this :

```
if(isi == 'A'){
    // your code
}
```

This is called comparison operation : " == "

Comment: I would recommend using the identity operator `===` over the equality operator `==`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/261564 for more info.

Comment: But in wc3school, they using '=' in IF statement :
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: @AnggaLisdiyanto No, they aren't.

Comment: "==" for equal to and
"===" for equal value and equal type

Comment: @Juhana is correct, they are using (`>`) and (`<`) and using assignment within the if statement, not actually in the `if ()` statement itself.

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned by hitesh upadhyay and Oliver you should use equality operator `==` and not assignment operator `=`.

Consider using switch in this case to produce cleaner code.

```
function PilihKeterangan(isi)
{
    var msg = "";
    switch(isi){
        case 'A':
            msg = "Sangat Baik : sangat aktif mengikuti latihan dan kegiatan ...";
        break;
        case 'B':
            msg = "Baik : aktif mengikuti latihan dan kegiatan ...";
        break;
        case 'C':
            msg = "Cukup : cukup aktif mengikuti latihan dan kegiatan Kepramukaan ...");
        break;
        case 'X':
            msg = "Kegiatan ini tidak dipilih oleh siswa / bukan menjadi pilihan siswa";
        break;
        default:
            msg = "Pilihlah predikat A/B/C/X.";
        break;
    }
    $('#keterangan').val(msg);
}
```

Comment: But in wc3school, they using = in IF statement :
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: w3schools is not always correct or affiliated in any way with the W3C please do not take it as an absolute source.

Comment: So like that?
So who is wc3school?

Comment: @AnggaLisdiyanto It's a private company who's using a misleading name on purpose. And it's w3schools, not wc3school.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply guys. :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be because you are using the assignment operator (`=`) rather than an equality operator (`==`), I would generally suggest using the identity operator (`===`).

The if clause must return a `boolean` value, an assignment does not.

The identity (`===`) operator behaves identically to the equality (`==`) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

This is covered extensively on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/261564)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single `=` you need to use a `==` for equality

Comment: Okay, but in wc3school, they using '=' in IF statement :
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp